# How to open Add Contact form through app

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, contacts-framework

How to open native Contact form with some prefilled data using `Contacts Framework`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add ContactsUI framework. Import it in your viewcontroller like this

```
 import ContactsUI
```

Add and Call this following method from respective viewcontroller.

```
  func addExistingContact() {
    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        let contactPicker = CNContactPickerViewController()
        contactPicker.delegate = self
        self.presentViewController(contactPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }

}
```